# Intel XDK AJAX Call with cordova 4.1.2 not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am not able to do ajax call with cordova  CLI version 4.1.2 on intel xdk (with latest update of intel xdk).

I have set the DOMAIN LIST as "*" .

Any help on this or its a known issue which has not been fixed till now (with latest intel xdk).

P.S: It works properly with Cordova CLI 3.5 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks krisrak ...
But with the latest update. I have specifically set "http://*" for Ajax call with the "Allow external application to launch" selected and ITS WORKING.

But not with (*) which is the super set of http://* . I would give the try what you have suggested and share my result

Answer (score 0):

In Intel XDK project settings -> build settings, uncheck the option "allow external application to launch from this domain", that is below the domain list.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cordova-cli-412-domain-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps

There was changes to Android whitelisting in Cordova 3.6 http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/09/08/cordova-361.html

More details about Cordova whitelisting is here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide_android_whitelisting